# Is it possible to have a clickable button in a tooltip's content and to use it without closing the tooltip?

Tags: .net, wpf, events, tooltip

In my WPF application, I have a tooltip that shows many messages with paging. The user should be able to see the next message by pressing next button. The problem is that when the next button is clicked, the tooltip closes. Is there a way to keep it open and handle the event?

Answer (score 1):

Click is a routed event and it bubbles up to the `Tooltip` in the `VisualTree` and `Tooltip` closes when this event occures. So I recommend to you to stop this bubbling.

Set the `RoutedEventArgs` Handled property to true

```
void NextButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //Application logic
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

Comment: I tried but seems it's not applicable. Seems that the tooltip's content [cannot be focusable](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/wpf/thread/bef8d64f-0fb2-4e8e-bc58-20637dd0aecf).

Comment: As suggested in the link, you should use popUp instead of tooltip.

Comment: @RV1987 I wanted to make sure that it's not possible in Tooltips before I handle the events myself